# How do we match the gifts present in an array with the boxes present in another array using pivot and partition method

Tags: c++, c

You are given a collection of N gifts of different sizes and N corresponding boxes. You are allowed to try a gift and box together, from which you can determine whether the gift is larger than the box, smaller than the box, or fits in the box exactly. However, there is no way to compare two gifts together or two boxes together for their sizes. The problem is to match each gift to its box. Design an algorithm for this problem with average-case efficiency in O (n log n)

Hint:

Take a box (as a pivot) to partition the gifts. Use the partition point of gifts to partition the box. Continue this way.
Please find the example and the approach taken below.

G: 19,15,5,16,20,2,11,17,4,10,8,18,12,13,1,9,7,3,6,14 B: 5,20,13,6,16,4,2,3,9,15,18,11,1,10,14,8,7,19,12,17

Take a random element of B as pivot for G, e.g. 8 partition G with this pivot.

Since each box has a match, this value will exist.

G is partitioned as

GL= 5,2,4,1,7,3,6 
GR=19,15,16,20,11,17,10,18,12,13,9,14

Box 8 is matched with Gift.

Partition the boxes with this pivot 8

BL= 5,6,4,2,3,1,7

BR=20,13,16,9,15,18,11,10,14,19,12,17

BL can only be matched GL, and BR can only be match GR

Solve the sub problem (BL, GL) and (BR, GR)

Comment: are you looking for help with a homework assignment? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Yes. Will be of great help if this can be achieved as I'm completely clueless.

Comment: propose something, do not just ask us to do your work, if we do for you you will learn *nothing*

Comment: Sorry I'm new to any this forum and haven't used any such forums. Please find the code I have tried below.

Comment: Smells like you can take a look at how [quick sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/) works.